# R, stringr::str_extract_all: Get all occurences specified in regex list

Tags: regex, r, stringr

Really simple, but I can get the 'greediness' of regex to work like I want. Say you have:

```
unlist(stringr::str_extract_all("XXXXSXTXXX","([A-Z]{2}[T|S][A-Z]{2})"))
```

This gives only the first match:

```
[1] "XXSXT"
```

How can I change the regex behaviour to give me both matches with S and T (without use two separate patterns), like:

```
[1] "SXTXX" "XXSXT"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `lookahead` for that with `perl=True` option for match in R.

```
(?=([A-Z]{2}[TS][A-Z]{2}))
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/23

Comment: Ah perfect!, I tried everything (even lookahead - but the wrong way)

Comment: I think an explanation is due here. It is not just a look-ahead that does the actual job here, the look-ahead is a kind of a "transport/vehicle" for the real "worker" - capturing group.

Comment: @stribizhev yes `lookahead` will traverse all possible path which is being captured by `groups`.